# Resize text in .pgf input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fonts, floats, fontsize

I have some wide graphics as .pgf files.
I include them in my .tex document as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{file.pgf}}
    \caption{the caption}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}` also shrinks the text inside the graphic. How can I rescale the graphic but fix the font size?

Comment: You should probably do the scaling inside the .pgf file directly.

Comment: Fine. Maybe that's the right way to go. Thanks.